# PHP string comparing with ===

Tags: php, string, authentication

I'm making a login script for my site.

It sends a `POST` (using `curl`) to another server with the user pass etc.
If the info is wrong it returns `Bad login`

But when I check the reply even if it's wrong it will say the login is successful.

```
if ($result === "Bad login"){
    $password_status = 'Wrong password.';
    $error = true;
}
```

i have also tried `strcmp` as well with no success.

Comment: What is `$result`? Where does it come from?

Comment: You say the reply is always successful but you left out that part if the `if statement`. Also I don't think you need to do a strict compare here (`===`).

Comment: @zerkms: it's the reply that came from a POST request using curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try var_dump($result) because it may contain other characters.

Maybe try:

```
<?php
if (strpos(strtolower($result), 'bad login') !== false) {
    $error = true;
}
```

Comment: @PeeHaa: It's an answer to his question, I think it should be an answer.

Comment: @Cyclone: It might be. However I don't see what the `strpos()` has to do with it. And it is very hard to say if this would be a solution since the OP didn't provided enough info.

Comment: @PeeHaa: It kinda seems obvious to me at least, that what this answer does is check if the string even contains "bad login". Of course, that probably means that they should just `trim($result)` most likely, but since this worked for OP then it works.

Comment: i'm just going by how he said the login is validated from another site using curl and he has the value in $result.  most likely there was whitespace at the least, or possibly a full html webpage.  strpos with strtolower should be enough to find "Bad login" if it was indeed in $result  - that's all

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact value of $result? and what is your full if statement?

$result will have to be an exact match, for example:

```
echo ('Bad login' === 'Bad login') ? 'True<br />' : 'False<br />'; // True
echo ('Bad login ' === 'Bad login') ? 'True<br />' : 'False<br />'; // False (Space after login)
echo ('Bad Login' === 'Bad login') ? 'True<br />' : 'False<br />'; // False (Capital L on login)
```

**Edit:**

This is how I would compare:

```
$result = trim(strtolower($badLoginVariable));

if($result === 'bad login') {
    // Do stuff here
}
```